# How to elegantly plot specific member(s) in a list of data structure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list as format below

```py
exampleList = [["name0",[[np.sin(1), 1], [np.sin(2), 2], [np.sin(3), 3]]], ["name1",[[np.cos(1), 2], [np.cos(2), 4], [np.cos(3), 6]]], ...]
```

Is there any way to concisely plot the same result of below without using a loop?

```py
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [np.sin(1), np.sin(2), np.sin(3)], [2, 4, 6], [np.cos(1), np.cos(2), np.cos(3)]...)
```

I have read https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html but failed to get a good method.